# TCP/IP through WLAN, Permission denied

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

This is my first aproach to java TCP/IP and I trying to figure out how the things work. I've made the jar for server in computer PC1 and a client jar in PC2, both connected to router. I'm trying to follow the steps [here](http://java-buddy.blogspot.com/2014/02/simple-example-of-tcp-clientserver.html) using a wlan interface. If I do in PC1

```
ifconfig wlan0
```

I get

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX  
          inet addr:192.168.0.101  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::213:2ff:fed0:abc8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3735 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3597 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2769175 (2.7 MB)  TX bytes:613767 (613.7 KB)
```

well, if I run the server code with the argument 64 as port number, I get this

```
Port: 64
Nov 10, 2014 3:07:13 AM comunicacion.JavaTCPServer main
SEVERE: null
java.net.BindException: Permission denied
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:382)
at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:128)
at comunicacion.JavaTCPServer.main(JavaTCPServer.java:74)
```

what am I doing wrong? How can I fix this? Must I create a network in PC1 first? All code are run in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception **ConnectionRefused** usually occurs when there is **no service listening** on the port you are trying to connect to.

There can be following problems:

1. **The server is not running.**
2. **The server is not waiting to accept connections.**
3. **You may be connecting to wrong port number.** You need to ensure both server and client use same port number.
4. **You might be starting the client before the server starts.**

The code you are using is fine. There are certainly only the above mentioned issues or some network issue. There can also be a firewall blocking the connection.
Sometimes your earlier instances of the client may leave the ports opened. So you may need to a different port again.

You can try to **ping the server** machine from you client.

It would be better if you first check the server and client on the same machine on *localhost*.

Comment: must I disconnect both computers from wifi router before test the code?

Comment: It is not necessary. While tesing on localhost i.e. 127.0.0.1, you don't need the wifi router. But for actual test on both computer, you need to connect to wifi router. Follow these steps for tesing on same computer: 1). Start the server code in a computer at port say 50000. 2). Start the client with IP as 127.0.0.1 and port 50000 on the same computer in which server is running.

Comment: now, it is running ok :D thanks , Kunjan, is it possible to send bytes through TCP/IP to a PIC to move a step motor remotely?

Comment: I guess yes it could be possible. But sorry I don't have any knowledge about embedded programming.

Answer (score 1):

In Unix based systems, ports below 1024 are **privileged**.You need **administrator** **rights** to access the port below 1024.

So using the port 64 gives an exception.

You should use a port number greater than 1024.

You may get some information for using ports below 1024 here:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/authbind.1.html

Comment: OK, I've started server socket with port 1025 with no error messagge. But when I try to start client with parameters inet addr 192.168.0.100 and port 1025 an Exception occurs, it says Connection Refused :-(